Can't set up google API
When I set up the Google Places API, I received a promotion that was only available for India. Since I'm in Vietnam, I chose the standard option.
enter image description here
but it didn't accept my Vietnamese credit card (which I had added before). Additionally, the dropdown for selecting a state only listed Indian states.
enter image description here
Has anyone else encountered this issue?
I want to enable the Google Places Autocomplete API and get the secret key for my project.

Why are you asking here?  This seems like a Google customer service problem.

"Basic Support
Basic Support is included for all Google Cloud customers. With Basic Support, you have access to our documentation and community support."
Im tried with documentation and now i trying with community support
